# Select only the entry of each user with the lowest time

Tags: mysql

I have a Table `USER` with:

```
USER_ID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
USER_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
USER_EMAIL VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
USER_TIME BIGINT NOT NULL
```

And i select the data:

```
SELECT USER_NAME, USER_TIME FROM USER ORDER BY USER_TIME
```

Now i get that for example

```
Peter, 18
Hans, 22
Peter, 33
Peter, 44
Hans, 45
```

I only want to have each user once and i only want to have the lowest time of each user. Is that possible with just one select statement?

So the result should be:

```
Peter, 18
Hans, 22
```

The following select statement is not correct for my problem:

```
SELECT USER_ID,USER_NAME,MIN(USER_TIME)
FROM USER
GROUP BY USER_ID
ORDER BY USER_TIME
```

because it does not sort correctly. if i have this list:

```
Peter, 18
Hans, 22
Peter, 33
queen, 15
Peter, 44
queen, 14
Hans, 45
```

With the statement above i get this result:

```
Peter, 18
queen, 14
Hans, 22
```

but as you can see that is not correct. it should be

```
queen, 14
Peter, 18
Hans, 22
```

I want it to be sorted over ALL results.

Comment: Why do you have a table called `user` with duplicate users in the table?  You should fix your database.

Comment: No i should not. There is no user registration or login or something. So every user can have multiple entries.

Comment: . . Then you have a user history table or a user login table, not a user table.

Comment: the name of the table is totaly unimportant for my problem ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `GROUP BY` and `MIN` function to achieve your goal.

```
SELECT USER_ID,USER_NAME,MIN(USER_TIME)
FROM USER
GROUP BY USER_ID
ORDER BY MAX(USER_TIME) DESC ;
```

Comment: i guess its close to the solution but not yet working. i get a result but it is not ordered by user_time. dont know why

Comment: Add `desc` in order by clause

Comment: No that is not what i mean. i want to sort ALL results.

Comment: Can you explain in question with more data?

Comment: i edited my post. i hope it gets clear. forget desc. i dont need descending

Comment: I added `MAX(USER_TIME)` in order by clause

Comment: THATS IT! thank you very much for your patient help!

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use something like:

```
SELECT USER_ID, USER_NAME, MIN(USER_TIME)
FROM USER 
GROUP BY USER_ID
ORDER BY USER_TIME DESC
```

You use agregate function `MIN` with `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: i guess its close to the solution but not yet working. i get a result but it is not ordered by user_time. dont know why.

Comment: It works for my custom query [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5fa9f/11) Do you need it to be sorted in descending order or what exactly you after?

Comment: I added DESC after the query to sort result in descending order.

Comment: Nah... hmm... how to explain... With your solution the results arent ordered... for example i have now first entry: Peter, 45, second entry: Hans, 35, third entry: petra, 38. The time of petra is 38 so it is higher than hans entry but appears after. it needs to be sorted over all results.